# How do i hide specific child node from rendered 3D model in android?

Tags: arcore

ANDROID ARCORE:
I want to hide specific child nodes of rendered 3D model?

Like we have hiding option in ARKIT by finding child nodes with names.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add some code to show what you have tried. If you are unsure what to add please take some time to read [ask]

Comment: You can use `node.getParent().removeChild(node);`

Comment: How do i hide specific node?  If you see in iOS, .dae or .scn files we can name each node and using names we can easily delete/hide. But in android, obj format gives only material names. There is no way to find exact node from obj file

Comment: Anyone help on this yet? I have the exact same problem. iOS I find by name, but on Android I can't find by name for some reason of the children nodes. If you figured it out, please share.

Answer (score 3):

Calling `removeChild(node)` and `addChild(node)` causes flickering, so rather hide with `node.renderable = null` and then show with `node.renderable = theNodeRenderable`.